# Coudn't enable JavaScript in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, redirect, phantomjs

My code is...

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.open("http://www.mangaumaru.com/archives/503925", function(status) {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

and "C:\>phantomjs main.js" result is this:

```
<html><head><title>You are being redirected...</title>
<noscript>Javascript is required. Please enable javascript
before you are allowed to see this page.</noscript>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is enabled by default in PhantomJS. The `<noscript>` element is always part of the source regardless whether JavaScript is enabled or not. When JavaScript is disabled the element is simply not rendered. Printing the source won't tell you much. You need to render a screenshot for example as `page.render("screenshot.png")` to see if the noscript element is visible.

When such a JavaScript redirect is done, it is usually triggered after some time. You need to determine what that time is for your page, but you would solve that for example either by waiting a little (until the next page is loaded):

```
page.open("http://www.mangaumaru.com/archives/503925", function(status) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(page.content);
        phantom.exit();
    }, 10000);
});
```

or you can do register to the page load event so that you you see that a second page was loaded:

```
page.open("http://www.mangaumaru.com/archives/503925", function(status) {
    page.onLoadFinished = function(status){
        console.log(page.content); // actual page
        phantom.exit();
    };
});
```